# How to place captcha on Django CreateView that uses Material Design Layout() feature

Tags: django, django-forms, captcha, django-material

I'm working in an existing codebase that uses [Django Material](https://pypi.org/project/django-material/).  There is a `CreateView` defined with a Django Material Layout:

```
class OurModelCreateView(LayoutMixin, CreateView): 
    model = OurModel

    layout = Layout(
        Row('field1', 'field2', 'field3'),
        Row(...)
    )
```

This view is getting lots of spam signups and so needs to have a captcha.  I use [Django Recaptcha](https://pypi.org/project/django-recaptcha/), and I've set up a number of captchas in the past.  However, I've never set one up without using a `ModelForm`.  If I create a Django model form and define the captcha field in the form as I've always done:

```
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
from captcha.widgets import ReCaptchaV3

class OurModelForm(ModelForm):
    
captcha = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV3)

    class Meta:
        model = OurModel
        exclude = ()
```

and then specify `form_class = OurModelForm` on the `CreateView`, the following error is raised by `ModelFormMixin.get_form_class()`:  "Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted".  This error is being raised because, though I've not explicitly specified `fields`, Django Material's `LayoutMixin` defines `fields`:  https://github.com/viewflow/django-material/blob/294129f7b01a99832a91c48f129cefd02f2fe35f/material/base.py  (bottom of the page)

I COULD drop the Material `Layout()` from the `CreateView`, but then that would mean having to create an html form to render the Django/Django Material form - less than desirable as there are actually several of these `CreateViews` that need to have a captcha applied.

So I think that the only way to accomplish what I'm after is to somehow dynamically insert the `captcha` field into the form.

I've dynamicaly inserted fields into Django forms in the past by placing the field definition in the `__init__()` of the Django form definition, but I can't figure out what to override in either `CreateView` (or the various mixins that comprise `CreateView`) or Django Material's `LayoutMixin` in order to dynamically insert the `captcha` field into the form.  The following several attempts to override `get_form` and `fields` in order to dynamically insert the `captcha` field do not work:

```
   On the CreateView:
       def get_form(self, form_class=None):
           form = super(OurModelCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
           form.fields['captcha'] = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV3)
           return form

       def fields(self):
           fields = super().fields(*args, **kwargs)
           fields['captcha'] = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV3)
           return [field.field_name for field in fields

       # fields is actually a list, so trying the following too, but it doesn't include the ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV3) anywhere at this point
       def fields(self):
           fields = super().fields(*args, **kwargs)
           fields.append('captcha')
           return fields
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried dropping `LayoutMixin` from the view? All it does is define `fields`, which you don't want because it's causing the `Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted` error.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks.  Yes, I know I could do that.  Please see my comment that starts with:  I COULD drop the Material Layout() from the CreateView,...

Comment: I saw that. I didn't suggest dropping `layout = Layout(...)`, only `LayoutMixin`.

Comment: Or another idea: Subclass `ModelForm` and override `__init__` to add the recaptcha field. Then Override [`get_form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class), and call [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory) with your form as the second argument. Then you can keep `LayoutMixin`.

Comment: Your first suggestion did it.  I had looked at the `LayoutMixin` code but still had the supposition that `LayoutMixin` was necessary for Django Material to even do the layout.  As you pointed out, `LayoutMixin` only defines fields (would be nice if the mixin naming made that clear!).  Removing `LayoutMixin`, creating a Django form with the captcha defined, and adding `form_class` to `CreateView` solves the problem. Thanks VERY much, and if you'll write up an answer, I'll mark is as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on the comment from @Alasdair above which pointed me to the answer, I solved this problem by removing Django Material's `LayoutMixin` from `CreateView`, creating a Django form with the captcha field defined, and then adding to `CreateView` the `form_class` for the Django form.  Also see my last comment above.  It was counterintuitive to me until I looked again at the code after @Alasdair's second comment:  the use of `LayoutMixin` on the `CreateView` isn't necessary for the `layout = Layout(...)` on the `CreateView` to work.